# bootstrap - Hide navbar on small screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this structure:

```
<div class="container"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
    <input id="searchBar">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>  
</div></div>
```

and I'm trying to hide the right navbar on mobile screens. I set it to xs-hidden, but it still shows up.

Is there a way to hide a navbar on xs screens?

Comment: Correct class is `hidden-xs`

Comment: I, embarrassingly tried to delete my post when I saw your comment... Well, I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.hidden-xs` css class (not `.xs-hidden`).

```
<div class="container hidden-xs"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
    <input id="searchBar">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked hidden-xs">
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Item</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>  
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

To help others and you reference the Bootstrap documentation "[Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)"

[image: Responsive utilities: Available classes]

As pointed out by Nicolapps you would use `.hidden-xs`

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row"
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-10">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something llike this stuff
you should set icon pointer events as none

```
.container {
position: relative
}

i {
position: absolute;
top: npx;
left: npx;
pointer-events: none;
}

select {
font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5, use:

```
.d-none .d-sm-block
```

ref:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/